# rename file and directory in linux by find or perl

Tags: linux

I need to scan all directories & files ander / directory
And to rename the host - "node1" with "node_STAR" in file name or directory name

Can some one have brilliant idea how to do that maybe with find or perl ( in order to insert this to my shell script)
Any way it's must be very fast in spite we scananing all Linux directories and files

example on - file

```
     /var/tmp/node1 will be /var/tmp/node_STAR file
```

example on - directory

```
     /etc/my_hosts/node1  will be /etc/my_hosts/node_STAR dir
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
rename 's/node1/node_STAR/' `find /var/tmp /etc/my_hosts -name 'node1'`
```

Answer (score 1):

Since passing the filenames via a backtick-call of find might fail if the number of affected files is large, it's better to use xargs:

```
find . -name '*node1*'  -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/node1/node_STAR/'
```

This command will replace all file and directory names containing the string `node1`starting at the current directory (`.`). If you want to replace only exact file names, remove the asterisks from the find parameter, and to restrict it to files or directories, use the parameter `type -f` or `type -d` respectively.

Comment: Using a backtick call will also fail if filenames include spaces, but so will the command shown in your answer. Use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`

Comment: Hi dennis - how it can be file with space?

Comment: @Dennis: Yep, you are right. Edited it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @yael: It's easy: Just enter `touch 'myfile with space'` and you have a file name with two spaces in it. Unfortunately, it's a perfectly legal character for filenames. Unfortunately because it leads to way too many problems if you are not careful, as I demonstrated myself :(

Comment: @yael: In Linux and Unix, any character except for null (0x00) and slash (/) can be in a filename, including space, tab, newline, carriage return and non-printing control characters.